# Getting SSL error while developing NodeJS app with on the local machine

Tags: node.js, windows, ssl

I've configured([server.js](http://pastebin.com/AnL7cg0M)) SSL support on one of mine projects.
It worked well both on my local PC and DigitalOcean's server.
But at some moment I've seen `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error:
[image: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR screenshot]

Comment: It might depend on your browser. If I am not mistaken the use of SSLv3 is no longer supported. Is your cert using SSLv3?

Comment: @Shawn chrome says it uses TLS 1.2 ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/u95PA3b.png))

Comment: For the current connection it is using TLS1.2 or is the server cert SSLv3? It might be trying to use compat fallback of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks on the internet adviced me to play with my timezone settings, but it doesn't help at all.
Others asked me to check is there any application which could be listeting port `443`, I thought it's useless because if any app has taken this port I'd get [EADDRINUSE](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_eaddrinuse_address_already_in_use) error, which I've haven't seen.
Anyway I decided double check it via terminal, running `netstat -a -o | grep 443` it terminal, and I've seen this:
[image: list of processes that use 443 port]
Well, crap. Let's get more info about this dude by `tasklist /v /fi "PID eq 6036" /fo list`:
[image: Search process with pid 6036]
When I killed skype process with `taskkill /pid 6036` everything worked like a charm.
Unfortunately as mentioned [here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Modern-Windows-for-users-on/How-to-change-port/td-p/1173550) it is unable to set any other port for Skype.

Used links:

- [Taskkill](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx)
- [Tasklist](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx)